# TweetIds is always null

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I am using a linq-to-twitter query to attempt to get a tweet (status)  and reply to that status, but the query always returns ID and TweetIds as null.  I attempted to use the statusId, but it went through as a tweet and not a response

```
 var tweets =
            await
            (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
             where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                   tweet.UserID == {UserId}
             select tweet)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciateed

Comment: Sorry, c# ......

Comment: It seems your code similar to [twitter samples](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20Statuses) and it means you have correct code. There are two explanations at list:

 - you do not have tweets here;
 - you are asking incorrect resource.

To check twitter answer for correct resource you could [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/:id).

Comment: I guess I had to add the @{ScreenNameResponse} before the response.  I got it working.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

From the [LINQ to Twitter FAQ](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/LINQ-to-Twitter-FAQ#4-why-are-screenname-andor-userid-properties-null-in-the-user-entity-response-from-twitter):

#### 4. Why are `ScreenName` and/or `UserID` properties null in the `User` entity response from Twitter?

The `ScreenName` and `UserID` properties are input only, allowing you to see the parameters you provided in your query.

- For v2.1.x, use the `Identifier` property, which has the `ScreenName` and `UserID` returned from Twitter.
- For v3.0.x and later, use the `ScreenNameResponse` and `UserIDResponse` properties.

A bit of background: Anything used as an input parameter is also looked at in the query response, so if a user omits the parameter in a query but the twitter response contains a value, it was being filtered out of the results. To fix this, I adopted a convention where any return parameters also match input parameters would have a 'Response' suffix. e.g. `ScreenName` (input) and `ScreenNameResponse` (output). To find which values are input, the docs for each API call contain the input/filter parameters.

Here's an example, from [LINQ to Twitter Samples code](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/blob/master/Samples/net46/CSharp/ConsoleSamples/StatusDemos.cs):

```
    static void PrintTweetsResults(List<Status> tweets)
    {
        if (tweets != null)
            tweets.ForEach(tweet => 
            {
                if (tweet != null && tweet.User != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "ID: [{0}] Name: {1}\n\tTweet: {2}",
                        tweet.StatusID, tweet.User.ScreenNameResponse, tweet.Text);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I had to add the @{ScreenNameResponse} before the response. I got it working. Thanks for the quick response.